# pandas dataframe filter by dateform that doesn't have dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I'm making some project to sort orders from many channels.

the problem is, I have to add note for dispatch date depending on customers needs.

the date will be put by me, through google spread sheet and its date form.

I'm using `gspread_pandas` module.

```
import gspread_pandas import Spread
s = Spread('myid', 'sheetname')
s.sheets
temp_df = s.sheet_to_df(index=False, headers=1, start_row=2, sheet='data')
```

`temp_df` is like below.

```
    name    item    quantity    dispatch_due
0   james   shoes   1           2017-11-27
1   john    shirts  1           2017-11-28
2   jack    pants   2           please add dispatch_due
3   lambo   gun     3           2017-11-143
```

I want to make a `dataframe` filtered only with dispatch_due is filled with right form of date. in case of `lambo(index3)`, I want to change it back to 'please add dispatch_due.

```
print(temp_df.dtypes)
```

the problem is, if I do like above, there is no *dtype* that I can deal with. all of the columns are 'object'.

```
name          object
item          object
quantity      object
dispatch_due  object
```

What can I would do with it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Google Sheets API doesn't really give back the type for the different columns. That being said, I think it could make sense to add a param like `dtype` or `converters` as found in `pandas.read_csv`. I'll look into that, but the answer provided by COLDSPEED should work for this specific use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime` with `errors='coerce'` to identify bad data and fix it.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.dispatch_due, errors='coerce')\
  .fillna('please add dispatch_due')

0        2017-11-27 00:00:00
1        2017-11-28 00:00:00
2    please add dispatch_due
3    please add dispatch_due
Name: dispatch_due, dtype: object
```

---

If you don't want the trailing timestamp, you could convert the date to `strftime` before filling `NaN`s.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.dispatch_due, errors='coerce')\
       .dt.strftime('%y-%m-%d').replace('NaT', 'please add dispatch_due')

0                   17-11-27
1                   17-11-28
2    please add dispatch_due
3    please add dispatch_due
Name: dispatch_due, dtype: object
```